# Python how to decalre numpy shape with (4,500)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

hello everyone i need user input to the numpy with shape (none,4,500) so how do i have to it?

and because when i print `numpy.shape` i get **()**

while i need shape with (4,500) and what kind of shape is it?

and how user input the numpy with the above shape

i have this but prints **()**

```
X_test = np.argmax('input')
print(X_test.shape)
```

does that mean X_test has no shape or the shape is not declared ?

Comment: You're asking Python (or rather `numpy`) what the `.shape` of the `np.argmax()` of the string `'input'` is. Why are you using `np.argmax()`? What are you expecting from passing `'input'` to `np.argmax()`?

Comment: i am sorry i do not know much about numpy i just want make a 2D numpy which user inputs strings like sentences

Comment: Numpy is most often used for numeric data, not text. While it's almost certainly possible to store text data that you get from the user in an array, it's not going to be very convenient for anything. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254), where you're asking about X (using numpy arrays for text), but your question doesn't really make any sense to the rest of us. Your real issue is Y (something else), but you haven't told us about it, so we can't really help you with it other than to say that numpy probably isn't the way to go.

Comment: iam thankful for your answering and information...  i have language modeling machine translation build with keras and used numpy to load and use the text data      and i asked in keras google group they told me if you want to test from user array should be the same as trained data

Comment: now iam confused i do not know how to test after i loaded the model in another script

Answer (score 2):

I think you are jumping into this problem without much knowledge of `numpy`.

```
In [155]: np.argmax('input')                                                                   
Out[155]: 0
In [156]: type(_)                                                                              
Out[156]: numpy.int64
In [157]: __.shape                                                                             
Out[157]: ()
```

I don't know why you use `argmax`, but what's happened here is:

```
In [158]: np.array('input')          # make an array from the string                                                               
Out[158]: array('input', dtype='<U5')
In [159]: _.shape                                                                              
Out[159]: ()                     # it's a single element array with 0d shape
In [160]: np.argmax(__)                                                                        
Out[160]: 0
```

`argmax` is the location of the largest element, and here just defaults to 0.  Being `numpy` it actually returns a numpy integer (not a plain Python integer), and as such it too has a `shape`, the 0d shape.

`(none,4,500)` shape you mention suggests you are working some `tensorflow` tutorial or the likes.  `none` is not a valid `numpy` shape term.

And you don't `declare` an array (or anything in Python).  You can create an array with that shape, e.g. `np.zeros((4,500))`.  But that's not very useful unless you are going to assign values to those 4*500 elements.

In a comment you talk about `the user inputs strings like sentences`.  Sounds like some sort of natural language study, or other machine learning.  You probably shouldn't ask the user to type in 2000 words; better to read them from a file.

In any case I think you need to do more basic reading about `numpy`.  In the next question, present more context.

---

Based on your last comments I was more or less right.  Except you seem to be further along with your modelling than I thought.  The code you showed didn't show much knowledge about `numpy`.  `declaring an array` might make more sense with `keras`.  I haven't worked directly with that; only helping people who stumble into `numpy` problems.

Comment: thanks for replying yes my model is machine translation with keras  and look to this line                                                                                                                                                    predictions = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis=2)    this is how they test it and the test comes from the txt

Comment: so if i want test the model or predict it i have to put sentences in a test.txt file and the run the -mode test the it will generate another file result.txt file which contain the out put of translation

Comment: what i want to do is test it from the user input and i firstly i saved the model and called it again another python file which is working but i dont know how to test it how to use model prediction